Why the token list remains non-blank after I execute `\tl_clear:N`? How to solve it?
Just like the title, I'd like to define a macro \foo for checking whether the token list \l_tmp_a_tl is blank, after I executed the command \tl_clear:N \l_tmp_a_tl, the output of the command \foo remains false. Also, \tl_gclear:N also doesn't work. How can I solve it?
The following is MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_tmp_a_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}
{
  \tl_if_blank:nTF \l_tmp_a_tl {true} {false}
}

\foo\par
\tl_clear:N \l_tmp_a_tl
\foo

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


Please note that while tmp is a valid module name as far as the naming conventions of L3 are considered, but you should really use another more speaking one for your real code.

A solution of the dilemma would be easier to understand if you stick to a simple rule

every argument denoted by n in the signature of the function must be in braces.

If you follow this rule, you will recognize what's going wrong:
\tl_if_empty:nTF { \l_tmp_a_tl } {true} {false}

checks whether the first argument is empty and it's quite clear it isn't, because it contains the token \l_tmpa_tl.
Note that n arguments aren't processed in any way, but just passed as they are to the function for being used somehow, depending on the function definition.
With an image, you're passing \tl_if_empty:nTF a bottle, so something.
To the contrary, arguments denoted by N should never be braced and \tl_if_empty:NTF will examine what's inside the bottle. Out of metaphor, in the former case you're passing the variable, in the latter the variable's contents.
Similarly, to \tl_map_inline:Nn you pass a token list variable and the mapping will be done on the variable's contents. Instead \tl_map_inline:nn will do the mapping on the (braced) explicit token list passed as argument.
Thus, for instance, after \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {abc}, the calls
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { -#1- }

and
\tl_map_inline:nn {abc} { -#1- }

would produce the same result.

You're testing the status of a token list variable, hence your argument is an N-type, not a token list input (n-type). Use \tl_if_empty:NTF or \tl_if_blank:VTF (depending on whether you want to test for emptiness or if spaces are considered empty as well).
Complete MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_tmp_a_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}
{
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmp_a_tl {true} {false}
}

\foo\par
\tl_clear:N \l_tmp_a_tl
\foo

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

(This yields true twice as a \tl_new:N results in an empty token list being created)
